# HTML meta "keywords". Worth including?

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

Do you use "**`keywords`**" meta in your site, knowing that [Google does not use them](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) (and has no plans) in page ranking, and perhaps even search?

Comment: I did some SEO work for a company for a while. Well a guy who ran it himself. #1 for "Web Marketing Australia" in google. He always used Keywords from what I picked up so I'd assume they have some value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you do; Google is not the only search engine in the web although its has the major market share.  There are other engines including Yahoo which use the Keywords META to some extent.

Comment: I agree. But always keep in mind that, IMHO, good (structured) content is the most important thing regarding SEO.

Comment: Absolutely, and any meta keywords should reflect the well structured content of that particular page.

Comment: Google has 85% of the search engines market. So, what other SE uses keywords?

Comment: As mentioned above; Yahoo (8-10% MS) still assign some ranking importance to meta keywords; you can even test it yourself as per this blog http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo-blog/index.php/meta-keywords/

In addition to this (and the other answers on this question); we have no idea what search engines are going to start doing in the future, regardless of what they might say today.

Comment: Maybe other SEs use meta keywords, but they put so little emphasis on it, it's not worth your time adding keywords for every page.

Answer (score 4):

No. **I don't want competitors knowing what I am trying to rank for**. Keywords are very valuable in some markets. If you found a good keyword phrase that is converting well (and your competitors don't know about it) do yourself a favor, and keep a monopoly on it.

Answer (score 3):

That is NOT a reason to abandon keywords altogether.

They are still indexed and searchable, and so still have a function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we do.  No one knows the exact Google (or any other search engine) algorithm.

In addition, lots of companies use "keywords" for internal websites that host tons of Html generated content.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard from so many people that Google doesn't use meta keywords, I'm not sure I'm convinced of that however. But, whether they do or they don't you should still use them because Bing and Yahoo (the other 2/3 or the big 3) still do use them. But remember to limit your keywords because (based on popular opinion) none of the 3 engines read past character 46.

Answer (score 0):

I did, because I didn't know that fact. Now I am thinking that **is not worth doing** so insignificant I see the "[energy conversion efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_conversion_efficiency)", even if we don't take Google in consideration, other SE seems do not take much attention to it...