# HTML5: What is the "correct" behavior for validation of unregistered <meta> tags?

Tags: validation, html, metadata

The following is valid 'HTML 4.01 Transitional' according to [the W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="revisit-after" content="30 days">
  <meta name="DC.Title" content="Website title">
  <title>Website title</title>
</head><body></body></html>
```

When transforming this code to HTML5, the `meta`-tag underwent some changes as [documented here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/). Thus, the following **should** be valid HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="revisit-after" content="30 days">
  <meta name="DC.Title" content="Website title">
  <title>Website title</title>
</head><body></body></html>
```

Except that it doesn't validate as apparently meta tags are supposed to be [registered](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) now.

**Problem:** The W3 documentation does not list restrictions on `meta`-tags as a new "feature" of HTML5, but they do not validate like they did previously in HTML 4.01 Transitional.

**Update:** While the [official HTML4 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4) does indeed not restrict the field values of the `name` attribute, the [HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.name.html) mentions the new restriction (unlike the "differences" guide). [Some posters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190594/html-meta-keywords-worth-including) suggest to not use `meta`-tags at all based on SEO arguments, but there have been many public and internal uses of `meta`-tags for cache control, documentation and storage purposes. Should there not be a way to turn valid HTML4 code into valid HTML5 code without relying on millions of meta-parsers to rewrite themselves automagically?

**Question:** What should we do in practice?

Comment: Why don't you want to register new values?

Comment: Why would anybody want to spam a public database with internal documentation/storage tags of many companies that were only intended to be used internally? Besides being a security/privacy issue, I see no rationale how this can be advantageous in any scenario.

Comment: For the same reason why you shouldn't invent new HTML elements: in the future someone might register the **same keyword** you use internally but with a **different meaning**. Sure, if the value is only useful to your site, it probably shouldn't be registered. But then, I'd also wouldn't use `meta` (but `script` as data block, or the `data-*` attributes on existent elements).

Comment: I agree that your response makes sense. But I still wonder why the W3C changed the semantics of the existing `meta` tags instead of introducing a new element (`script` or `data-*` attributes as you suggest or something different) and require registration of those? That wouldn't influence validation of existing pages and anybody who needs a registered alternate tag variant would be free to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, just leave the meta tags as they are. Even if the validator complains, it doesn't make a single bit of difference to anyone using your website.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. The reason I am not perfectly happy with it is that validation *does* serve a purpose - I can rely on a webpage being predictably rendered in a browser. I may accidentally introduce a genuine error on a specific page; with proper validation such an issue has a higher chance of being detected. So maybe you know if there already is 1) either a parser for filtering "invalid" errors in the w3validator output or 2) an alternative validator out there that focuses on and reports relevant information only?

Comment: "I can rely on a webpage being predictably rendered in a browser." - Absolutely and categorically not the case. Validation does NOT guarantee this and never has. Validation is a technical check of your page against a formal definition of HTML, it has no relation to browser quirks or bugs. There are invalid pages which are guaranteed to display correctly in every browser ever made, and valid pages which have cross-browser compatibility problems ranging from the minor to the catastrophic.

Comment: Validation may have "no relation to browser quirks or bugs", but it does have some relation to correct browser behavior. While I agree that it is too extreme to say that "validation will protect me from browser bugs", I do not agree with the opposite extreme of "validation serves absolutely no useful purpose." Validation has in the past helped me to find bugs in my HTML-code (some of which resulted in incorrect rendering) and has thus saved me time. Giving up on validation sounds like a last-resort option rather than the preferred solution for me.

Comment: I agree that validation serves some purpose, and I'm not suggesting giving up on validation. It's a question of recognising exactly what the validation errors mean, and acknowledging that they are technically correct, but that you still don't have a problem with your document.